# Перевод String в double и наоборот

Tags: java

Есть строчный массив, нужно с него получить значение и перевести его в double вот так:
"1.2s" = 1.2;
Как это лучше сделать?

```
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    String[] iso_third = { "32s", "1s", "1.2s", "1.6s", "2s", "2.5s", "3s" };
    String iso_string = (iso_third[1]).toString();
    double iso_num = Double.valueOf(iso_string);
    System.out.println(iso_num);

    }
}
```

Код выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: "1s"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at SimpleDotComTestDrive.main(SimpleDotComTestDrive.java:6)
```

Comment: ну так все нормально, не может же дробное число содержать в себе `char`

Comment: `Double.valueOf(s)` должен получать строку, которая содержит число в одной из допустимых форм (`3`, `3.4`, `3.4e5`) и может содержать пробелы или табуляции перед ним и после него. Вы же передаете ей строки вида `1.6s`. Буква `s` не может быть частью числа. Ели вы уверены, что строки всегда содержат только число и букву `s`, то можно просто делать `double d = Double.valueOf(array[i].replace("s", ""));`. Иначе, возможно, надо использовать регулярные выражения. Кстати, `String iso_string = (iso_third[1]).toString();` лишнее, достаточно просто `String iso_string = iso_third[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
package uz.gigalab.test;

public class SimpleDotComTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] iso_third = {"32s", "1s", "1.2s", "1.6s", "2s", "2.5s", "3s"};

        for (String s : iso_third) {
            s = s.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
            double iso_num = Double.parseDouble(s);
            System.out.println(iso_num);
        }
    }
}
```